# Changing umask of apache on ArchLinux

Tags: apache, archlinux, umask

This didn't work:

[Setting the umask of the Apache user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428416/setting-the-umask-of-the-apache-user)

Arch doesn't have a `/etc/apache2/envvars` file, and changing the `/etc/rc.d/httpd` script didn't change anything.

Maybe someone can enlighten me how/where to exactly change the rc-script, so apache has an umask 002

Comment: How did you detect that it doesn't work?

Comment: @initall - I set the umask command in the rc-script and restarted the server with the rc-script. I let php via apache create a new directory, but it hat the same permissions as before.
I'm not an expert on rc-scripts/shellscripts, so I'm probably doing something just very wrong here :/

Comment: Do you run PHP as a module or via CGI in your setup?

Comment: If you set the umask via the PHP umask function, does that work?

Comment: haven't tried it, but as the directories are created by a framework, I'd rather set it with apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying again, strangely editing the `/etc/rc.d/httpd` file works.

Just put

`umask 0002`

Right after the `#!/bin/bash` and everything works as it should.

No idea why it didn't work before, but well...