# Error: PID file /run/httpd/httpd.pid not readable (yet?) after start. (Apache)

Tags: apache, archlinux

Does anyone know what can cause this error in Apache's error log (particularly in Arch Linux):

```
PID file /run/httpd/httpd.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
```

The error is not stopping Apache from running normally (once it is started), but is potentially slowing down my service restart time significantly.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) does  `/run/httpd` exist (and is that where you'd like to put the pid file? (2) is it writable for whatever user apache runs as?

Comment: `/run/httpd` does exist. Apache is running under the user:group http:http but the mode of the pid file is root:root. Why is systemd creating the pid file as root:root? Is there anyway to change this?

Comment: Probably, the parent process is running as `root` (unless you actually start apache as the HTTP user instead of as root, see also [the remarks about the User directive here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#user)). An option is using a more desirable umask (making the pid file readable, yet not writeable by `http`).

Comment: The parent process is running as root, but these lines are in my httpd.conf file: `<IfModule !mpm_netware_module> <IfModule !mpm_winnt_module> User http Group http </IfModule> </IfModule>`

Comment: I don't run archlinux (in Debian I'd put it in `envvars`), but [this question seems to deal with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477899/changing-umask-of-apache-on-archlinux) (although the suggested editing of a `rd.d` script is something I normally want to avoid). Are your btw _sure_ it slows the starting down? I would think it only delays/blocks the detecting of a start, but apache runs nonetheless.

Comment: I no longer think it's slowing the start up process down. But it is still an error I'd like to get rid of.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to adjust the file `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/apache.conf`. The default values are wrong. You have to change this

```
d /run/httpd 0755 root root -
```

to

```
d /run/httpd 0755 http http -
```

.

After restarting apache the PID file will be created with `chown http:http` and not `chown root:root`.

**Ressources**:

- https://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-general/2013-July/033891.html
- https://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-general/2013-July/033900.html

Comment: I ran an update today and it stopped working too. On the other side after restoring to `root` it stopped taking forever to start. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

My take is that this bug is a feature: Nothing I've done has been able to get rid of it (tried everything suggested here and then some) yet the software runs just fine. So, I take it as a slightly mis-written success message - I've started!

Answer (score 0):

I have met this issue:

> PID file *.pid not readable (yet?) after start.

Recent days, my apache server was compiling from the package-issued version is `httpd-2.4.12.tar.gz`. Here is my httpd.service contents, following this my problem got fixed. Hope this can help anyone who have met this.

```
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl start -DFOREGROUND
PIDFile=/run/apache/apache.pid
ExecReload=/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl restart
ExecStop=/user/local/apache/bin/apachectl stop
PrivateTmp=True

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: When you start a process in the foreground, you should use `Type=simple`. Furthermore, `PIDFile` is not required.