# How to set default permissions for new files created with php

Tags: php, umask

Hi I am running a centos server and I want to know how I can set the default chmod of a newly created file that is created by php like fopen. At the moment it is doing 644 but I want 666 so where can I specify this setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Linux, PHP has a chmod() command that can be invoked to change file permissions.

See the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

For a default setting you might try what [Patrick Fisher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161182/patrick-fisher) states here: [Setting the umask of the Apache user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428416/setting-the-umask-of-the-apache-user?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
[root ~]$ echo "umask 000" >> /etc/sysconfig/httpd
[root ~]$ service httpd restart
```

Comment: Yes I know this but i am talking about the default value without changing it :)

Comment: I edited to better address your question. This is supposed to work with Centos.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `umask()` immediately before the fopen() call, but umask shouldn't be used if you're on a multi-threaded server - it'll change the mask for ALL threads (e.g. this change is at the process level), not just the one that you're about to use fopen() in.

e.g.

```
$old = umask(000);
fopen('foo.txt', 'w'); // creates a 0666 file
umask($old) // restore original mask
```

It'd be easier to simply chmod() after the fact, however:

```
fopen('foo.txt', 'w'); // create a mode 'who cares?' file
chmod('foo.txt', 0666); // set it to 0666
```

Comment: I only need `umask($old)` when I want to restore the original mask for the current script, right? Or does the `umask` call make a permanent change?