# UMASK, Virtualmin, WordPress and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, umask, digital-ocean

I've deployed a new VPS with DigitalOcean. It's a standard LAMP stack and I'm testing a WordPress installation after creating a new "Virtual Server" in Virtualmin but it's UMASK is 022 and I need it to be 002.

So I updated /etc/login.defs line 151 and restarted Apache and then created a new Virtual server but it didn't respect the UMASK as I anticipated. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428416/setting-the-umask-of-the-apache-user

Comment: Thanks, I'll respond to this when I've had a chance to try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going here logging into Virtualmin and then to Webmin.

```
Webmin > Servers > ProFTPD Server > Edit Config Files
```

And change the UMASK there inside the file from 022 to 002?