# Permisson issue for directory and all sub dirs

Tags: permissions

I have a script that each night checks /original for all sub directories that are older than 30 days, zips them in /original and then scp's them to a remote ftp, and then deletes the zip and  directory. Pretty simple.

But it is failing due to a permission error on /original and the subdirectories.

I need my user to have full permission over /original , all its subdirectories , and any new directories that are created (about 350 per day). I am unsure even after researching how exactly to do this.

Comment: Which operating system? Can you include the output of "ls -ld /original /original/some_subdirectory"? That would help figure out what your issue really is.

Comment: RHEL 5.3
/original = drwxrwxr-x 10622 drew apache 299008 Mar  4 12:49
/original/sumdir = drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Mar  1 14:08

Answer (score 0):

The permissions on directories are described using the bits that show up as `drwxrwxr-x` in `ls -l`. After the first `d` (for directory), there are three groups of `rwx`, for read-write-execute permissions for the user, group, and others, respectively.

In your example, the subdirectories are owned by user `apache`, group `apache` and only writable by the user, not the group. You probably need them to be writable by the group `apache`. Make sure that `drew` is a member of that group. Then `drew` would be able to delete files from those subdirectories, and the subdirectories themselves.

The ensure that those directories are created group-writable, that is usually controlled by the umask in effect when the Apache server runs. You'll want the umask of 002 for that. See this question/answer for how to do that: [Setting the umask of the Apache user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428416/setting-the-umask-of-the-apache-user/1315147#1315147).