# Changing default permission in Flask application with Apache web server

Tags: python, apache, permissions, flask, file-permissions

I have a flask application that creates directory with this code:

```
if not os.path.exists(target_path):
    os.makedirs(target_path)
```

With the created directory the default permission is `0755`, and the owner and group is `_www`. 
So, only the owner can write in the directory.

I always have to modify the permission manually to `0775` to make some files in it.

[image]

How to make the default directory permission as `0775`? I use apache for web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has something to do with Apache setup.

For Mac:

1. Open `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`
2. Add `<key>Umask</key>` and `<integer>002</integer>`
3. Restart with `sudo apachectl restart`

I found the solution from [this site](http://the-mac-os-x-server-mailing-list.10970.n7.nabble.com/httpd-LaunchDaemon-umask-td2784.html), for linux I guess [Setting the umask of the Apache user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428416/setting-the-umask-of-the-apache-user) can give some hints.

Comment: 1. since El Capitan you can't edit certain system files / directories (including System/Library) even as root:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899

To be able to write you have to disable csrutil:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208481/258780



2. adding the suggested changes to the plist didn't work for me - apache continuous to write files and directories in 755/644 mode...

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out: the <key> and <integer> tags have to go inside the top level <dict> tag. I've put it first within the EnvironmentVariables' <dict> tag. Then I had to "sudo apachectl stop" and then "sudo apachectl start" instead of simply restart.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
if not os.path.exists(target_path):
    os.makedirs(target_path, mode=0775)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, flask or apache ignores the mode and makes the permission as 0755.

Comment: Could that be a `umask` issue?